# move a column ,including th, between tables in jQueryUI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tt3ceLbf/4/)

I have two example tables with subject titles in the first cells.

```
<table class='sort connect'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='ui-state-disabled'></th>
            <th>Person 1</th>
            <th>Person 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Age</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>23</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Job</td>
            <td>Clerk</td>
            <td>Policeman</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table class='sort connect'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='ui-state-disabled'></th>
            <th>Person 3</th>
            <th>Person 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Age</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>46</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Job</td>
            <td>Student</td>
            <td>Firefighter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've made the first child of `th` and `td` unsortable since they are titles. Is there any way to move other columns, one at a time (`td:nth-child,th:nth-child`), to the other table using jQueryUI sortable?
How can I make a whole column sortable in the `change` or `start` event?

Here's my expected output:

```
<table class='sort connect'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='ui-state-disabled'></th>
            <th>Person 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Age</td>
            <td>18</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Job</td>
            <td>Clerk</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table class='sort connect'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class='ui-state-disabled'></th>
            <th>Person 3</th>
            <th>Person 2</th> // sorted
            <th>Person 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Age</td>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>23</td> //sorted
            <td>46</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class='ui-state-disabled'>Job</td>
            <td>Student</td>
            <td>Policeman</td> //sorted
            <td>Firefighter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS code:

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
    var $originals = tr.children();
    var $helper = tr.clone();
    $helper.children().each(function(index)
    {
      $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
    });
    return $helper;
};

$(function() {
    $( ".sort" ).sortable({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
      var see = ui.item.index();
          console.log(see);
      $(this).find('td:nth-child(see),th:nth-child(see)')
    },
     helper: fixHelperModified, 
     cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
     connectWith: ".connect"
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

Comment: Does your HTML structure need to stay the same or can that be edited? I.e. Create a table for each column and then put them in a div and make the divs sortable and the sortable elements the tables themselves

Comment: I don't have time ATM to write any code, but i'm thinking the solution is a bit more abstract than a literal move.   Something that does a count of td's in a row, and does a modulus on the it to get all tds in a row, ie, we want to move table with children els td3/td6/td9.      Maybe someone can run with that.   HTH

Comment: I'm not sure whether this helps, but for me this looks like a data representation issue. AFAIK, a row represents a *record* and column represents an *attribute* value of that record. For me, here `person` is a record and `age`, `job` etc are attributes of person. (*Is `person1`, `person2` etc an attribute of `age` or `job`? well, not for me.*) Based on that, [**you're structure should be like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/tt3ceLbf/21/). Right, not *the* answer for question hence a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/tt3ceLbf/16/)?

It's a workaround for what you're asking, but it does basically the same thing, just fix the styling, spaces, etc. as you'd like

**HTML**

```
<div class="sortableContainer sort connect">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td height="20px"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person 1</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>18</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Clerk</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person 2</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>23</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Policeman</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sortableContainer sort connect">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td height="20px"></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Job</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person 3</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>17</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Student</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Person 4</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>46</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Firefighter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
td, th {
    border:1px solid #222
}
.red {
    background:red
}
.ui-state-disabled {
    opacity:1
}
.sortableContainer>div {
    display:inline-block;
}
table {
    border-spacing:0px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $(".sort").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connect"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: I haven't thought about that. It seems to be a good solution. The thing I need to take care of is the length of the content in the second and third tables to make sure their height and width match the first table . Otherwise the whole structure would be broken.

Comment: @RedGiant I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, could you emphasize a bit?

Comment: @RedGiant I think I know what you mean now, by any chance, is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/tt3ceLbf/22/

Comment: yes that's what I was trying to say. I wanted to keep equal heights between the tables so if one of the cells contains more text it won't break the whole structure.

Comment: @RedGiant Is there anything else you are experiencing difficulties with regarding the code I've presented? Or is there anything you would like to have added or changed?